# Kivy app doesn't work on android phone, although it works on the computer

Tags: python, android, debian, kivy, buildozer

I have  some problems with making apk using buildozer on debian: when I launch my app on debian it works, but when I launch it on my android phone I get this :

```
07-25 19:56:58.939 14073 14190 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
07-25 19:56:58.939 14073 14190 I python  : AND: Ran string
07-25 19:56:58.939 14073 14190 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
07-25 19:56:59.345 14073 14190 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 21)
07-25 19:56:59.346 14073 14190 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
07-25 19:56:59.360 14073 14190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_19-07-25_0.txt
07-25 19:56:59.361 14073 14190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.0
07-25 19:56:59.362 14073 14190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
07-25 19:56:59.363 14073 14190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Jul 23 2019, 20:08:31) 
07-25 19:56:59.363 14073 14190 I python  : [Clang 6.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/clang 183abd29fc496f55
07-25 19:56:59.365 14073 14190 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "android_python"
07-25 19:56:59.385 14073 14190 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Clock       ] Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and make sure to compile Kivy
07-25 19:56:59.387 14073 14190 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-25 19:56:59.387 14073 14190 I python  :    File "/home/vlad/test/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 8, in <module>
07-25 19:56:59.389 14073 14190 I python  :    File "/home/vlad/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 319, in <module>
07-25 19:56:59.390 14073 14190 I python  :    File "/home/vlad/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 26, in <module>
07-25 19:56:59.392 14073 14190 I python  :    File "/home/vlad/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/clock.py", line 363, in <module>
07-25 19:56:59.395 14073 14190 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libpython2.7.so" not found
07-25 19:56:59.395 14073 14190 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

(logs are from logcat)

What can I do to fix it?

P.S. Here is my buildozer.spec: https://pastebin.com/DrVeqXt2

Comment: Welcome Stack Overflow. Did you install Cython on your computer? As per error message, `07-25 19:56:59.385 14073 14190 I python  : [ERROR  ] [Clock       ] Unable to import kivy._clock. Have you perhaps forgotten to compile kivy? Kivy contains Cython code which needs to be compiled. A missing kivy._clock often indicates the Cython code has not been compiled. Please follow the installation instructions and make sure to compile Kivy
`.

Comment: @ikolim, everything works fine on the computer and Cython is installed.

Comment: This has to do with the libraries. I would suggest you to (a) Check the requirements in the buildozer file to ensure if you have added all the stuff you are using in the app and (b) If that's alright, you're probably using a library that has C bindings and would not be readily compatible on Android, for example if you are using a library like matplotlib or scikit-learn, chances are it wont work on Android.

Comment: @DipanshuJuneja, I use paho-mqtt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution - I've just used vevnv and installed all necessary libs.