# .py file works on pc but .apk doesnt work on android [crashing]

Tags: kivy, apk, buildozer

Im in trouble. I made some codes with [**Python3**].It all works fine when i run on **PyCharm** or **Python3(on terminal)**.And then im using buildozer for create apk file.It works fine without any error.But when i upload apk to android device apk crashes.Im using **lxml,requests,threading,kivy** libraries and thats all in buildozer requests.

When i try to get image from kivy on FIRST page , it works fine but on next page when i try to get same images it crashes on Android.As same , my some of strings (not english words) works on first page as i want , but they're failing on next page and they turn into unicode symbols.

I found this:
[Kivy app doesn't work on android phone, although it works on the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57205131/kivy-app-doesnt-work-on-android-phone-although-it-works-on-the-computer)

But he didn't explain how did he made it and i can't ask him how! because of my low reputation.He solved this problem somehow and he closed his own question without any solution...

Comment: For recent versions of Android, you can no longer just list the permissions you need. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/doc/source/apis.rst#runtime-permissions).

Comment: Also, try connecting your android device to your PC, then run `buildozer android deploy run logcat`, and look at the output.

Comment: Thanks for answering mate.But I'm using genymotion for check my apk. How can i check my output logs.Because i had tried **buildozer android deploy run logcat** with kivy launcher, created and checked _../kivy/<project>_ file. But i didnt see any output like logs.txt or error.txt.[I checked root folder apks for check folders].

Is there any documentation for how to get error logs on kivy launcher with genymotion. Thanks already...@John Anderson

Comment: Btw my virtual device's API: 26 [8.0] but im gonna try permissions and share result here..

Comment: This virtual device **(API: 26 [8.0])** allows apk for sdcard writes and reads..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for advice @John Anderson.I found my fails on log. When i try to get web informations which is contain unsupported unicode chars (I mean my local alphabet characters), kivy taking'em with unicode names so my Image source list fails and apk crashes.Im happy because found **aLogcat ROOT** apk so i can check all python commands easily.